# Self Signed certificate and Root CA Certificate are same?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Root Certificates are Self Signed certificates and are used to sign other certificates.

My question is can we use any self signed SSL certificate to sign other certificates or there is any data that tells that this Self Signed certificate can't be used to sign other certificates ?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112768/why-are-self-signed-certificates-not-trusted-and-is-there-a-way-to-make-them-tru

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Hugo

Comment: Sorry, i was not aware of that...@Jww

Answer (score 1):

A self-signed certificate which has the basic constraint for CA set to true can be used as a CA certificate to sign other certificates. Of course, the client still needs to be configured to trust this new root certificate so that the certificates it signed can be successfully validated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Steffen Ullrich.

So, The only difference between a Normal Self Signed Certificate and a Root CA certificate is the Basic Constraints ?

And we can't sign using a given Self Signed certificate, if the Basic Constraint is not CA ?

Comment: @JatinderJindal: Usually self-signed certificates are created with CA true but one could also create one with CA false, only that the last one gives often problems at least with OpenSSL based applications. Thus a self-signed certificate is usually also a CA certificate and can be used to sign other certificates. If CA is not true one can in theory sign another certificate, but the signature should not be accepted when validating since it was not created by a CA.

Comment: Thanks.
What i'm getting from you reply is that it is not forced to mark CA true or false.It is just for the information.

The CA constraint can be false for a given self signed certificate and it can still be used to sign other certificates.

So, it take us to the conclusion, that all self signed certificates can be used to sign other certificates.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
Or i'm getting this right ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use all self-signed certificates to sign other certificates. But, unless CA is true in the self-signed issuer certificate the validation of the issued certificate inside the client will fail - at least if the client is not broken. *"It is just for the information."* - it is a __critical__ information. The client MUST adhere to the information there and MUST NOT accept an issuer who has not CA true.

Comment: Thanks.

By the client you mean the browser right ?

I'm not able to understand what will fail.

If i have a self signed certificate with CA set to false, then i'm able to add it to trust store of browser and nothing fails.

My question may be dumb

Comment: @JatinderJindal: Do I understand you correctly that you have a self-signed certificate "cert-A" with CA false which you have added as trusted into the browser. Then you have used this self-signed non-CA cert-A to sign a certificate "cert-S" for a server. And then you have an server which uses this server-certificate cert-S which got signed by the non-CA cert-A to successfully authenticate against the browser without explicitly trusting this server certificate cert-S too? If this would work then this would be a serious bug.

Comment: Yes,what you have mentioned is my query.

Although i have not signed a certificate from that self signed certificate with CA set to false yet.

I'm just able to add that into my trust store,and what i think is that when i sign a server certificate from this SelfSigned certificate then the browser will not show any problem.I might be thinking wrong here

I just wanted to know, what would be the behavior, what will fail ,at what stage?

Comment: @JatinderJindal: To quote myself: *"... the __validation of the issued certificate inside the client will fail__"*. And yes, browser is also considered a client but it can also be a mobile app or many more things.

Comment: The validation of the issued certificate will fail,even if the self signed ca certificate is in the trusted store of browser ?

Comment: @JatinderJindal: exactly. If the self-signed cert in the trust store has not CA true a client will not accept certificates issued by it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Will give a try to this, and will share  the results here.

Comment: I have also a query regarding Intermediate CA and End Entity.

Do you know any place on the internet where i can discuss this,
Searched a lot but nothing is satisfactory enough.

I'm not sure if possible can you please help me over skype regarding some queries.
If not,its fine.no prob.

Comment: As jww already pointed out - a good place for this kind of questions is security.stackexchange.com. But I recommend first to look for existing questions there because there exist already questions where the whole process of certificate validation is explained, including the role of intermediate certificates.

Comment: okay..Thank you...

I went there... but i think i just need to discuss some things with some expert...might be i need to consult some one offline...

What i see is...every one knows how to use it...but no one explains how it works...

Thank you very much...